# How to apply Multithreading in pyQt5 application

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5

```
def upload(self):
    # Upload File and convert it to dataframe and fill a column data to a dropdown
    # Return this dataframe 'df'

# User will select a FType from Dropdown and then below verifyFType function will be activated

def verifyFType(self):
    try:
        if(FType == "DH"):
            # Activate DH_ValidateFunction()
            # Activate Filter Function to filter data from dataframe
        elif(FType == "HSC"):
            # Activate HSC_ValidateFunction()
            # Activate Filter Function to filter data from dataframe
    except:
        pass

# One of the functions will be activated at a time 

def DH_ValidateFunction(self):
    # Calculations on some columns of pandas dataframe and return that modified dataframe
    # return final calculated dataframe 'df'

def HSC_ValidateFunction(self):
    # Calculations on some columns of pandas dataframe and return that modified dataframe
    # return final calculated dataframe 'df'

# On the basis of validation Function and final dataframe returned there will be dropdowns to filter
# data from dataframe "df"

def filterDate(self):
    # This will filter date from the dataframe "df"
    # Return filtered date dataframe "df_DATE"

def filterName(self):
    # This will filter Name from the dataframe "df"
    # Return filtered Name dataframe "df_NAME"

def EXPORT_CSV(self):
    # Export either df , df_DATE or df_NAME whatever user want at the time 
    # df.to_csv('table.csv) or df_DATE.to_csv('table.csv) or df_NAME.to_csv('table.csv)
```

My problem is If user filtered only date and want to proceed and export the current dataframe to csv ,how can I do that I am confused. I tried switch case but severely failed. I think multi threading can solve this issue...[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are currently doing and what you want to achieve? From your question, that's not very clear, and the code you're providing is almost useless as it's the attached image.

Comment: I don't see any problem description (you're just describing a task) and I'd suggest you start working on this for a start. When you have an actual problem, come back. Also, it might sound harsh, but you picked a technology (multithreading) with no or little clue what it does, but somehow you decided that it's related to your task. This is not a well-informed decision.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I understand you don't have much time to look deep into my issue but If you want I can elaborate it otherwise there is enough information in the form of small pseudo code , If I will write all of the code people will start telling that's a lots of code I need pseudo code.

Comment: @musicmante I have used function names such that people easily understand the code and Image is also related to the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use threads and run app with one thread, and something else with another you can make a function to run the application.

> Code

```
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        
def Run_Loop():# This function will run a while loop 
    while True:
        text =  input('Type Here: ')
        if 'break' in text:
            break
        else:
            print(text)


def Run_App():# This function runs the ui
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow) 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

t1 = threading.Thread(target=Run_App)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Run_Loop)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: While theoretically your solution would work for normal situations, GUI toolkits normally require to be executed in the *main* thread, while external thread cannot (directly) interact with it, so a QThread is mandatory for this situations. Also, your Ui_MainWindow is imcomplete, as the central widget is never *actually* set as such.

Comment: Nice try @Iron Man but that is slightly unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved by adding signals to the main thread of the code i.e. where UI Widgets are declared and then filtering dataframes inside the respective function. This allowed me to forget about activating filters and I only passed that dataframe which was required in the filters .